# Tensorflow: AlreadyExistsError Another metric with the same name already exists

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: AlreadyExistsError
Another metric with the same name already exists.
  File "/Users/sean/Documents/GitHub/VIQ-Intern-Projects/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
```

I have tried to uninstall keras. Then another error happens. Keras was not found.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises due to mismatch of `TensorFlow` and `keras` version available in your system. Make sure you use same version of `Tensorflow` and `Keras` to execute this code.

Check the existing version of `Tensorflow` and `keras` using below code:

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)

import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

If you find any difference in `versions`, install the same version of `keras` as `tensorflow` to fix this issue.

Suppose, you have `tensorflow_version = 2.6.0`, then install `keras` in same version using below code:

```
!pip install keras==2.6.0
```

or

```
#you can import keras from tensorflow while running your code.
from tensorflow import keras 
print(keras.__version__)
```

Try executing the above code again.
 Let us know if issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me is uninstalling keras and installing version 2.6.0
using pip.